# Grid view RowEditing event validation exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view and this grid view is data bounded to my database. In my grid view, I have an edit button where when user clicked the edit button, text box will show up and the user can change the existing text in the grid view. I got all of this working so far. I made my own validation method that work well. However, when I am trying to apply it to my `gvAddedEmployee_RowEditing` Event before my `FillGrid()` method, it gave me this error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

in my first line of my validation method.

```
private string ValidateRow(int rowIndex, DataRow row)
    {
       string employeeID= ((TextBox)gvAddedEmployee.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtEmployeeID")).Text;
      .....
     }
```

Here is my RowEditing Event

```
  protected void gvAddedEmployee_RowEditing(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //back up before editing
        DataSet dsDetail = (DataSet)Session[GlobalVariables.SessionKey_];

        Session[GlobalVariables.SessionKey_Before_Editing] = dsDetail.Copy();

        gvAddedEmployee.EditIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        DataRow row = dsDetail.Tables[0].Rows[rowIndex];

        //Error
        string errMsg = ValidateRow(rowIndex, row);
        divErrorMsg.InnerHtml = errMsg;

        FillGrid();

    }
```

I am not sure how this can be fixed, help will be appreciated.

Here is my other method that used exact the same code

```
protected void gvAddedEmployee_RowUpdating(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        DataSet dsDetail = (DataSet)Session[GlobalVariables.SessionKey_];

        DataRow row = dsDetail.Tables[0].Rows[rowIndex];

        string errMsg = ValidateRow(rowIndex, row);

        if (errMsg.Length == 0)
        {
           //code
        }
    divErrorMsg.InnerHtml = errMsg;
    Session[GlobalVariables.SessionKey_] = dsDetail;
    FillGrid();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The only reason behind this exception is that your TextBox control is not found during the execution of this line of code :**

```
((TextBox)gvAddedEmployee.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtEmployeeID")).Text;
```

You can check for a few things here.

- Check the spelling of the control ID supplied here. Correct if wrong.
- Check the values of `rowIndex` and `row` respectively.
- Check the GridView ID in which you are trying to find your control. Sometimes more than one GridViews are used and we end up using the other GridView rather than the correct one.

Just for better debugging purpose, you can try to separate the finding and converting of the TextBox line of code into two parts : 1.) Find the GridView row object. 2.) Find the Control using that row object.

**UPDATE :**

It looks like you might need to rebind your GridView before accessing it in RowEditing event since it is losing its state as you might not have used a DataSource. Check this link for a reference : [Finding control in RowEditing Event](http://forums.asp.net/t/1513945.aspx?Unable%20to%20Find%20Control%20in%20RowEditing%20event%20of%20GridView%20)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thank you for your respond, I have checked what you've suggested above. I am not sure if it works, It is because when I tried the exact same code in the `gvAddedEmployee_RowUpdating` Event, The code work fine

Comment: How do you pass the two parameters into that method ?

Comment: Do you mean RowIndex and Row? I have updated my code in my question how I do it in RowUpdating

Comment: But somehow it cannot find the control in rowEditing events

Comment: It looks like you might need to rebind your GridView before accessing it in RowEditing event since it is losing its state as you might not have used a `DataSource`. Check this link for a reference : http://forums.asp.net/t/1513945.aspx?Unable+to+Find+Control+in+RowEditing+event+of+GridView+

Comment: I see, I fixed the problem now, thanks for your help :)